# My kitten ate a lemon seed

Tags: cats

Not really sure what to do about This. It's only one seed but she's my baby could this cause any issues with her?

Answer (score 2):

All parts of lemons are toxic to cats so you need to get your kitten to your vet for treatment. This is not something that can wait, so you need to go to the vet right now.

[Please read this article at wagwalking.com about lemon poisoning in cats](https://wagwalking.com/cat/condition/lemon-poisoning).